# react: отрисовка разных компонент с параметрами в зависимости от значения переменной

Tags: javascript, reactjs, словари

подскажите как более правильно решить следующую задачу:

есть несколько разных компонент с разными параметрами: `<Panel1 data = {this.state.data1} />` и `<Panel2 value = {this.state.value2} />` и т.д.

они отрисовываются строго по одному (т.е. одновременна несколько не отрисовываются) в зависимости от значения переменной `this.state.panel`

Сейчас делаю так:

```
<>
    {this.state.panel === 'panel1' && <Panel1 data = {this.state.data1} />}
    {this.state.panel === 'panel2' && <Panel2 value = {this.state.value2} />}
    ...
</>
```

все работает, вопросов нет

но может есть более корректный и правильный способ?
просто смущает, что используется одна и та же переменная `this.state.panel` и можно сделать покороче

т.е. что-то на подобии питоновского `get` для словарей:

```
{
    'panel1': <Panel1 data = {this.state.data1} />, 
    'panel2': <Panel2 value = {this.state.value2} />
}.get(this.state.panel, <></>)
```

Comment: Попробуйте обернуть выбор в функцию. `fnc(name) { const x = { panel1: <Panel1 props />} return x[name] }`, ну а в рендере просто `<> {fnc(this.state.panel)} </>` у себя попробовал, работает

Comment: вопрос тогда - надо же передать пропсы причем они разные для разных компонент (т.е. это как-то через неопределённые параметры функции сделать), и интересует вопрос - когда будет создан компонент - при отрисовке или когда я его задам в словаре - во втором случае было бы не желательно получить создание сразу всех компонент (по ресурсам будет накладно)

Comment: Компонент будет создан при отрисовке, как раз на основе входящего параметра. Пропсы, судя из вашего кода, вы уже получаете и лежат они у вас в этом компоненте в this.state. в функции так же пропишите необходимые пропсы для каждого компонента. Если хотите сделать совсем универсальный компонент, то добавьте второй параметр в функцию и туда передавайте пропсы